# MVC5 - using clockpicker to populate model

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Firstly I am self teaching myself MVC so none of this may be best practice and the question may be considered MVC 101.  I have googled and tried various things for days so in frustration I am looking for help.

I am using MVC5, EF6, and Bootstrap 3

My objective is simple - I want to display a view that lets the user input a time using a clock-style timepicker for Bootstrap [The actual Clockpicker found here on GitHub](https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker).  The result of which is then populated back to my database when the user clicks create on the view.

I cant seem to get it working however.  Below I have included a simplified version of the Model, Controller and View.  In the view I can get the clockpicker to display using HTML that I found in examples but I am not sure how to bind to my model.  If I use html helper methods using the way I have been doing for other bootstrap elements, it wont display the clock picker.  If I code it up as per the example, it will display the clockpicker but I then don't know how to bind the result back to my model and therefore database.

If you have any example code or can point me to somewhere that may explain how I should do this I would appreciate it.

I hope the question makes sense.

**MODEL**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ATAS.Models
{


public partial class Authorisation : IControllerHooks
{

    public long AuthorisationId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10)]
    public string AuthorisationNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime FinishTime { get; set; }


}
}
```

**CONTROLLER** (I have just included Create Action)

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ATAS.Data;
using ATAS.Models;

namespace ATAS.Controllers
{
    public class AuthorisationsController : Controller
    {
    private DataManager db = new DataManager();     

    // GET: /Authorisations/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.AuthorisedEmployeeId = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeId", "FullName");
        ViewBag.PaymentTypeId = new SelectList(db.OvertimeTypes, "PaymentTypeId", "Description");
        ViewBag.AuthorisingEmployeeId = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeId", "FullName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Authorisations/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="AuthorisationId,DateAuthorised,StartTime,FinishTime")] Authorisation authorisation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                            if (authorisation is IControllerHooks) { ((IControllerHooks)authorisation).OnCreate(); }
            db.Authorisations.Add(authorisation);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AuthorisedEmployeeId = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeId", "FullName", authorisation.AuthorisedEmployeeId);
        ViewBag.PaymentTypeId = new SelectList(db.OvertimeTypes, "PaymentTypeId", "Description", authorisation.PaymentTypeId);
        ViewBag.AuthorisingEmployeeId = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeId", "FullName", authorisation.AuthorisingEmployeeId);
        return View(authorisation);
    }
```

**VIEW** (CREATE.cshtml)

```
@model ATAS.Models.Authorisation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Authorisation</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Clockpicker:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="clockpicker" type="text" placeholder="Select time" data-autoclose="true">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FinishTime, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FinishTime, new { @class = "clockpicker" })<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FinishTime)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    }

    <div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

@section pagespecific {
<script src="/scripts/plugin/clockpicker/clockpicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // PAGE RELATED SCRIPTS



        /*
        * CLOCKPICKER
        */

        $('#clockpicker').clockpicker({
            placement: 'top',
            donetext: 'Done'
        });

    })

</script>
}
```

**The PROBLEM**

*****This approach displays the clockpicker but I dont know how to bind to the model*****

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Clockpicker:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="clockpicker" type="text" placeholder="Select time" data-autoclose="true">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*****This approach wont display the clockpicker*****

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FinishTime, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FinishTime, new { @class = "clockpicker" })<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FinishTime)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you will notice I have left a couple of other data elements in the controller (employeeId etc..)  My actual model and view do contain these so it is not in error, I just forgot to clean it up before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after sleeping on it...  I have worked it out.

The problem was always in how I wired together the script.

```
@section pagespecific {
<script src="/scripts/plugin/clockpicker/clockpicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    // PAGE RELATED SCRIPTS



    /*
    * CLOCKPICKER
    */

    $('#clockpicker').clockpicker({
        placement: 'top',
        donetext: 'Done'
    });
   })   </script>
}
```

I used a [id selector](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_id.htm) instead (#clockpicker) of a [class selector](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_class.htm) (.clockpicker)

Goes to show sometimes just describing the problem can create the epiphany required.